# MSVC: shift count negative or too big

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I am trying to wrap my head around a warning I get from MSVC. From what I can tell, the warning seems to be bogus, but I would like to be sure.

I am trying to convert an off_t to an offset in an OVERLAPPED. Given an off_t named offset and an OVERLAPPED named overlapped, I am trying the following:

```
overlapped.Offset = static_cast<DWORD>(offset);
if constexpr(sizeof(offset) > 4) {
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = static_cast<DWORD>(offset >> 32);
}
```

MSVC complains about the bitshift, pretending the shift count is either negative or too big. Since it's clearly not negative - and even MSVC should be able to tell that - it must think it's too big.

How could it be too big? The code in question is only compiled if the size of an off_t is greater than 4. It must therefore be at least 5 bytes (but probably 8), and given 8 bits to the byte meaning a minimum of 40 bits, which is more than 32.

What is going on here?

Comment: Is your `if constexpr` inside a template? Because it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Assuming your *description* of the diagnostic is correct (and why did you not quote it?), MSVC is clearly wrong, so file a bug.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking **reproducible example**.

Comment: @Quentin can you tell me where in the standard it specifies that if constexpr only works when used inside a template? Because I can't find it.

Comment: No, but please have a look [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50051473/3233393) :)

Comment: @Quentin: `if constexpr` works in non template. The statement is discarded, (but it still requires to be a "valid" statement).

Comment: @Jarod42 So, [in this case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RekhKs5VScrw9R1s) is clang wrong or the fact that the statement only rises a warning (UB, I guess) is not enough to consider it "invalid"?

Comment: @Bob__: Bitshifting integers is never ill-formed. It may invoke UB, and compilers can *warn* about that. But the compiler shouldn't refuse to compile it, even if it can determine at compile time that the code will always invoke UB.

Comment: What exact version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: I am using VS2017.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the assignment into overlapped.OffsetHigh, and not your explicit shift, that is causing the warning? The following code generates the same warning  on VS2015 compiling for x86 32-bit:

```
struct Clump
{
    unsigned int a : 32;
    unsigned int b : 32;
    unsigned int c : 32;
};

unsigned int x = 0;
unsigned int y = 0;
unsigned int z = 0;

Clump clump = { x, y, z }; // This is line 1121.

1>E.cpp(1121): warning C4293: '<<': shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

But removing the bit-fields, there is no warning:

```
struct Clump
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
};

unsigned int x = 0;
unsigned int y = 0;
unsigned int z = 0;

Clump clump = { x, y, z }; // No warning.
```